# Not able do Azure key vault integration with databricks using terraform/programmatic

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I have a keyvault and databricks created. I have created secrets in keyvault and is there any terraform script/programmatic way to do Key vault integration with Databricks.

Comment: Could you please, provide more details (e.g. what you tried to find and failed, what you want exactly to achieve, maybe share part of the code if you don't mind etc.)?

Comment: Hi , I have a requirement Integrate key vault with databricks. We have sectrets placed in key vault.  keyvault and databricks already created. We need to integrate through programmatically. I was researching and could not find any terrafiorm script. Could you please suggest me to complete this task through any script. Otherwise we have to use manually.

Thanks,
Nag

Answer (score 0):

In [Databricks Labs Terraform](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/09/11/announcing-databricks-labs-terraform-integration-on-aws-and-azure.html) provider there are [databricks_secret_scope](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/secret_scope) and [databricks_secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/secret) resources, which work pretty well with Databricks-backed secret scopes. Please check if these are everything you need. You can proxy `azurerm_key_vault_secret` with something like

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "y" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

resource "databricks_secret_scope" "x" {
  name = "databricks-backed"
}

resource "databricks_secret" "y" {
    key = "secret-sauce"
    string_value = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.y.value
    scope = databricks_secret_scope.x.name
}
```

Otherwise you can try creating [Azure Key Vault-backed scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope) and importing it as `terraform import databricks_secret_scope.object <scopeName>`. Currently it's not possible to create AKV-backed scopes programmatically, but that may (or may not) change in the future.